# Javascript wrapping each item in an array with an anchor tag in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data model like this..

```
var tags = ["hello", "world", "foo"];
```

I would like to display it in my view like this, each wrapped in anchor

```
#hello #world #foo
```

View..

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag}}</span>
```

Desired Results:

```
 <span><a>#hello</a></span>
 <span><a>#world</a></span>
 <span><a>#foo</a></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should add tags variable inside controller scope & then you coulduse interpolation directive `{{}}` on html to display and create an href tag.

**Markup**

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags>
   <a ng-href="{{'#'+ tag}}">{{'#'+ tag}}</a>
</span>
```